# Realtime database storage issues in firebase of android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Authentication,verification of new user is working properly but in real time database,none of the user info is getting stored.

/*in firebase method*/

```
public void addNewUser(String email, String username, String description, String website, String profile_photo){
    User user = new User( userID,  1,  email,  StringManipulation.condenseUsername(username) );

    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users))
            .child(userID)
            .setValue(user);


    UserAccountSettings settings = new UserAccountSettings(
            description,
            username,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            profile_photo,
            username,
            website
    );

    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_account_settings))
            .child(userID)
            .setValue(settings);

}
```

Comment: By default all access to your database from clients is disabled to prevent abuse. See the [documentation on security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart).

Answer (score 0):

As Frank says you must enable your read , write permissions into your rules from your database

[image]

Then inside you can change the following parameters

Allow users to read all the data from your database but not write if they are not authenticated

```
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth!=null"
 }
```

Allow users to read and write documents inside your database without authenticating (not secure)

```
 "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
     }
```

Or simply use the best option that is allowing read and write only when the users are signed in with any of the [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) options

```
"rules": {
            ".read": "auth!=null",
            ".write": "auth!=null"
         }
```